# Fabric does not seem to be utilizing connection cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I have a Fabric script that I'm using to create an inventory in a data center.  The way I read their execution model it should reuse connections to a machine.

Example:

```
host =      run('hostname')
os_version = run('cat //etc/redhat-release')
uptime =    run('uptime')
ip_addr =   run('hostname --all-ip-addresses')
```

The above creates 4 seperate connections.  I could create just one connection by chaining the commands together, but I'd prefer not to for readability and my own idiosyncrasies

Is there a way to force it to reuse the cache or should I just give up and use one chained command?